# Sending HTML by Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Im responding this to a Jquery Ajax call and it works well:

```
var jSonTestResultReport =@"{ ""html"" : ""I am text!"" }";
```

The Javascript receives it and takes the text and presents it in a `Div`, i can see it saying `"I am Text"`.

But when i try to do this:

```
var jSonTestResultReport =@"{ ""html"" : ""<li style=""color:green;"">I am text</li>"" }";
```

i get the error of

> unexpected token c.

How can send `html` by `Json`?

Comment: What is the exception exactly? And the StackTrace?

Comment: in the 2nd snippet, the quotes around `<li ...>` are doubled up, but that's not the case in the top one. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape your "" qoutes like \"" in the `<li ... >` otherwise JSON will die because its a text delimeter

```
var jSonTestResultReport =
     @"{ ""html"" : ""<li style=\""color:green;\"">I am text</li>"" }";
```

Comment: you say with " in JSON that the string is ended but when you want to use an " in the string you need to delimit it with \ so it will be \" but because of c# @ thingy its \""

Answer (score 7):

```
var jSonTestResultReport =@"{ ""html"" : ""<li style=""color:green;"">I am text</li>"" }";
```

will create a json string as

```
{ "html" : "<li style="color:green;">I am text</li>" }
```

which is not valid. `unexpected token c.` comes from the first letter of `color`.

Use a [real json parser](http://json.codeplex.com/) instead of forming json manually.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { html=@"<li style=""color:green;"">I am text</li>" });
```

**PS: `var jSonTestResultReport =@"{ ""html"" : "I am text!" }";` is not compilable.**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the jQuery.parseJSON method this is more clearer and readable then the way you are using with lots of double quotes

e.g.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"html": "<listyle='color: green;'>Iamtext</li>"}');
```

Also to speed things I would suggest you make use of JsonLint validator to validate your json object